# Cheap high-capacity (disk, not bandwidth) hosting options

Tags: web-hosting, cloud-hosting, dedicated-hosting, amazon-s3, storage

So, the website I run is up to 8TB of photos now. I store them on a cheap dedicated server (€64/month, 3x4TB RAID 5), and back them up to Google Cloud Services. GCS is costing me about $80/month now.

The main box is going to be full within a week or two, so I need to do something.

The "easy" option, is just to buy another 8TB box. But my monthly bill will then be (64 + 64) euros + $80 = 128€ + $80 = ~£170. Once that box is full and I have to use 16TB backup at GCS it'll be £230/month.*

So, what are my options for 16TB of backed up space for less than £230/month. Anything?

If I hosted the files primarily at GCS/S3/etc, could I forego a backup? Do we consider google/amazon safe enough that my data would never be at risk? Even if that is the case... a simple mistake on my part could delete the lot. Not ideal.

I have definitely considered running the backup myself at home, but I feel it's prone to human error (me) and it'd kill my home internet at times (uploads are peaky, so I'd end up downloading 100GB a night once a week). Even if I manage to get 50Mbit/s overnight from BT (hah) that's 5 hours of bandwidth, and realistically it'd probably snare me up for 24 hours.

### Thanks!

* It'd actually be more, as my main webserver is 67.50€/month on top of that figure, but that's not really relevant to this question!

Comment: Can you move the photos to a CDN? If so, then that may be a good answer. Cheers!!

Comment: Surely a CDN is even more expensive than GCS/S3 etc?

Comment: I have no idea. I used to be a web host over a decade a go but so much has changed. My sites are on monster servers I built, HP, DEC, IBM, SGI, Compaq, Dell, Cobalt, Cubix, etc. from back in the day. I have a few newer ones with monster raids. So I have stayed out of the hosting market and cannot tell you about prices or who is good these days. It was just a thought to get you by since CDNs seem to be the rage these days.